# incorrect week_of_year

Tags: java

Have next function to get week of year:

```
static public Integer getWeek(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(1);
    cal.setTime(date);
    Integer week = cal.WEEK_OF_YEAR;
    Integer month = cal.MONTH;
    if ((week == 1) && (month == 12)) week = 52;
    return week;
}
```

Call the function with date=02.01.2013

What I see in debug:

1. date = Wed Jan 02 00:00:00 SAMT 2013
2. week = 3
3. month = 2

I want to get: week=1, month=1. Right?

Where am I wrong?

JRE 1.6

Thanks a lot for advance.

Comment: The cal.WEEK_OF_YEAR and cal.MONTH are constants I think. You'll want a cal.getDayOfWeek(). Give me a minute and I'll find the syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR` and `Calendar.MONTH` are static constants Calendar uses to look up fields. You want

```
Integer week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
Integer month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Also, note that (I think) January is considered month 0.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot. what's stupid syntax error. I have correct syntax 2 rows below... Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html there's the documentation. It can help you if you have further problems.

Answer (score 0):

`public final static int WEEK_OF_YEAR = 3;` is inside source of Calendar.

When you access `WEEK_OF_YEAR` it prints value of this field, it would be treated like accessing static field of `Calendar` class.

If you want get week, you need to do `Integer week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);`